# Setting custom spatial reference/coordinate system to shapefile using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, coordinate-system

I have a python code which converts JSON text file to a shapefile. I have to set coordinate system to this shapefile created. I do not want to access the .prj file from my computer as this code will be embedded in a web toolbox.

Comment: What is your GIS software platform?

Answer (score 2):

There's a Python code example for doing this under [Define Projection](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000077000000).

Comment: @PolyGeo.. ya I used that. It worked , I wanted that only. Thanks

Comment: How did we know he.she was on the ESRI platform? Is it safe to assume that all new posters who don't specify their platform are using ESRI?...curious...

Comment: It sounded like ArcGIS/ArcPy and I had answer at fingertips so did not take time to be certain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set a shapefile's coordinate system without the .prj file. Without knowing your platform it's hard to provide advice. You mention a 'web toolbox' and python.  If you know the input coordinate system of your JSON text file(which I'm betting is WGS84 lat/lon). You could build a generic .prj file on the fly to kick back to the user to accompany the generated shapefile.

Something like:

```
body='GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984"'
body+=',SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]]'
body+=',PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]]'
fout=open("c:/whereverIamstagingmyshapefileoutput/myprj.prj","w")
fout.write(body)
fout.close()
```